# SELECT from multiple tables on Azure Mobile Services

Tags: sql, angularjs, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

i'm using Mobile Services with Javascript Backend to my Ionic App and i need to make a select that join multiple tables.
Here's the deal:

I have 3 tables in my SQL Server on Mobile Services:

**Places**: id, name, description, type, city, id_user.

**Images**: id, id_place, img1, img2, img3.

**User**: id, name, email, picture.

In my AngularJS Code i've the following:

```
var table = client.getTable('Places');
var userid = $localStorage.idusuario;
$scope.ReadPlaces = function(type, city) {
var q = "SELECT p.*, i.*, u.picture, u.name, u.email FROM Places as p INNER JOIN User as u ON p.id_user = u.id INNER JOIN Images as i ON p.id = i.id_place WHERE p.type = " + type + " AND p.city = " + city;
  table.read({query: q}, {user: userid}).done(function(result){
  //do something
  }, function(error) {
  //do something
  }
};
```

And here is my Places table read script:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
  //CASO PRECISE, APAGAR DAQUI ATÉ...
  var mssql = request.service.mssql;
  var q = query;

  mssql.query(q, {
      success: function(results) {
          request.respond(statusCodes.OK, results);
      }
  });
  //...AQUI
  request.execute();

}
```

And what i need to do is **SELECT EVERYTHING FROM PLACES WITH ALL THE IMAGES FROM THAT PLACE AND SOME DATA FROM THE USER WHO UPLOADED THAT PLACE**.

and i get a 505 error.
So what am i doing wrong?
The examples i've seen showed me to do like this.

### UPDATE

I'm now trying with CustomApi, but the documentations seems a bit poor to me, so here's what i have so far:

My "ShowAllPlaces" api script:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
var mssql = request.service.mssql;
var q = "SELECT p.*, u.picture, u.name, u.email FROM Places as p INNER JOIN User as u ON p.id_user = u.id";
mssql.open({
    success: function(con){
         con.query(q, {
             success: function(results){
                 response.send(results);
             }
         })
    },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("error is: " + err.message);
        }
})
```

};

And my AngularJS code:

```
client.invokeApi("buscalocalcompleto", {
    method: "get"
  }).done(function(results){
    console.log(results);
  }, function(error){
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```

But still not working :(

Comment: I wouldn't do this in your table script.  Set this up as a custom API.  Tables implement OData v3 specification and you may not be allowing the adjustment of the query properly that is required for a table script.  If you need offline access, then sync each table separately and do the join on the local device.

Comment: @AdrianHall i'm now trying with customAPI and i'm searching on how to do so. I updated the code, could you take a look? And i'll not use offline access

Comment: You call an API like this: `client.invokeApi('buscalocalcompleto', { method: 'GET' }).then(successFn, failureFn);` - check out my blog at http://shellmonger.com for an example (Day 20 and Day 21 are what you want).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use mssql.open unless you are opening a separate database from the one that your Mobile Service normally uses for its data storage. Also, send an HTTP result code with your response:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var mssql = request.service.mssql;
    var q = "SELECT p.*, u.picture, u.name, u.email FROM Places as p INNER JOIN User as u ON p.id_user = u.id";
    mssql.query(q, {
        success: function(results){
            response.send(200, results);
        }
    });
};
```

This answer is assuming you are using Mobile Services, and not the newer Mobile App Service.

Comment: Just wondering what will be the difference if I use Mobile App service?

Comment: See the App Service SDK reference here: http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_data_execute.html#~execute